# tablesorter stickyhead widget enabling checkboxes jumps to top of the table

Tags: jquery, checkbox, tablesorter, sticky, head

I have got an issue with a tablesorter widget stickyhead http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-sticky-header.html

There is a table with many rows, scrolling down forces the header to stick to the top of a window. So it is always visible.

In the first column of the table I have a checkbox element in each row. Scrolling down the table and clicking any of the lower checkboxes forces a jump to the top of the table. I would like to prevent this.

See my fiddle example in the comments below.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried stopping the event from propagation? Give us a jsfiddle  .

Comment: the thing is, I can't find an object to stop the propagation, is it a table, or a header or checkboxes. I even do not understand what triggers the jump.

Comment: try adding a `click` event to the `checkboxes` and stop the propagation using `event` object.

Comment: Your demo has a js error... `clickedRow is not defined`

Comment: @Cerlin Boss: stopping event from propagation doesn't bring anything.it is defined. it is not shown here.

Comment: can you give us a fiddle to play with?

Comment: is the jump similar to anchor (#) click jump? also is it adding # to the URL after jumping?

Comment: @CerlinBoss: stopping event from propagation doesn't bring anything. the jump behavior doesn't add any # to the URL.

Comment: use [visual event](http://sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2) to check if there is any code which is assigned to the element ,which does this jump

Comment: @Mottie: the function clickedRow is defined. It is not shown in the example, it has no effect on the jump issue; this function is responsible for the clicking the rows' td elements, except of the very first td where the checkboxes are, and bringing an alert window to the front. clicking the rows doesn't force the jump. it only happens when I click the checkboxes in the lower rows.

Comment: here is a fiddle example. I have never done fiddle before, so it was a good starting point. http://jsfiddle.net/4jhzn8p6/ in this example, try to scroll down and check any of the lower rows' checkboxes.

Comment: In that demo, set `stickyHeaders_filteredToTop` to `false`

Comment: I did so, and it works in that demo. But it doesn't in my code. I have found a place where I refresh the table, calling $("#myTable").trigger("updateAll",[true]). This triggers the jump. Setting$("#myTable").trigger("update",[true]) does the job. The later updates only the tbody part of the table and unfortunately removes the functionality of the custom elements in the sticky-header. Like it does with sticky-header checkbox. Scrolling down in the demo turns sticky-header on, but removes the checkbox. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've seen [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/4603/) from the [wiki Home page](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/wiki#more-demos). It doesn't appear to have the issue you describe - probably because of the `return false` code in the `mouseup` function.

CSS

```
table.tablesorter tbody tr.odd.checked td {
    background: #8080c0;
    color: #fff;
}
table.tablesorter tbody tr.even.checked td {
    background: #a0a0e0;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Script - set the `columnWithCheckboxes` and `resort` variables as desired.

```
// add parser through the tablesorter addParser method
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'checkbox',
    is: function (s) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s, table, cell, cellIndex) {
        var c, $c = $(cell);
        // return 1 for true, 2 for false, so true sorts before false
        c = ($c.find('input[type=checkbox]')[0].checked) ? 1 : 2;
        $c.closest('tr').toggleClass('checked', c === 1);
        return c;
    },
    type: 'numeric'
});

$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blackice',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'stickyHeaders'],
        headers: {
            0: {
                sorter: 'checkbox'
            }
        },
        initialized: function (table) {

            // column containing all of the checkboxes (zero-based index)
            var columnWithCheckboxes = 0,
                // resort the table after the checkbox status has changed
                resort = false,

                ck, $hdrCheckbox,
                c = table.config,
                wo = c.widgetOptions,
                $t = $(table);

            $hdrCheckbox = $t
                .add(wo.$sticky)
                // make checkbox in header set all others
                .find('thead th:eq(' + columnWithCheckboxes + ') input[type=checkbox]')
                .bind('change', function () {
                    ck = this.checked;
                    $t
                        .children('tbody')
                        .find('tr td:nth-child(' + (columnWithCheckboxes + 1) + ') input')
                        .each(function () {
                            this.checked = ck;
                            $(this).trigger('change');
                        });
                    // make sure stickyHeader checkbox gets updated
                    $hdrCheckbox.prop('checked', ck);
                })
                .bind('mouseup', function () {
                    return false;
                });

            $t.find('tbody tr').each(function () {
                $(this)
                    .find('td:eq(' + columnWithCheckboxes + ')')
                    .find('input[type=checkbox]')
                    .bind('change', function () {
                        $t.trigger('updateCell', [$(this).closest('td')[0], resort]);
                    });
            });
        }
    });
});
```